# Mongoid getting no server is available matching preference

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, sidekiq

I have a bunch of sidekiq jobs running that are failing with the following error when I'm trying to perform a query to the DB:

```
No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x70249928071560 tag_sets=[] server_selection_timeout=30 local_threshold=0.015>
```

This seems to happen randomly, and not all the time. My mongoid.yml is structured as following:

```
hosts:
    - XX.XXX.XXX.X:27000
    - XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:27000
  database: acbde__production
  options:
    connect_timeout: 20
    read:
      mode: :secondary
    max_pool_size: 800
    replica_set: acbdeReplset
```

Anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether mongodb is actually running.

You can use `mongo --host IP --port PORT` to check connection.

Answer (score 0):

Most often this is happening because the application is trying to use clients across forks.

To do this properly, follow the instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#usage-with-forking-servers) and use the guidance [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-create-client/#troubleshooting) for troubleshooting.